# Change text position on Infragistics UltraCheckbox

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics NetAdvantage for Winforms. By default, the text on a checkbox appears to the right of the checkbox. Is it possible to get the text to display to the left of the checkbox? I cannot find the property that controls the text position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you need to use is called [`CheckAlign`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinEditors.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraCheckEditor~CheckAlign.html) and you should set it to one of these values:

```
 MiddleRight 
 TopRight 
 BottomRight
```